# Jquery .On() after page has loaded

Tags: jquery, function

```
 function jpPlayClick(){
      $('.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item').off('click', jpPlayClick);
      //Code stuff
  };
```

Here's what I had before: `$('.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item').on('click', jpPlayClick);`

and this worked by only running it once. However I need to do it when the page has fully loaded instead by using

```
$(document).on("click", '.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item', function () {
            jpPlayClick();
});
```

But this runs through each time instead of once. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Within your function you could remove the delegated event handler by doing something similar to your new `on` syntax: `$(document).off("click", '.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item')`. However, James Donnelly's answer is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.one()` if you only want something to execute once.

> The  `.one()` method is identical to `.on()`, except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.
>
> — [jQuery's `.one()` Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(document).one("click", '.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item', function () {
    jpPlayClick();
});
```

You'd need to place this outside of your `jpPlayClick` function though, otherwise each time that's called it'll re-create this event handler.

Comment: I have a problem. This code disables all my other click handlers with that class too. I only wanted it to do that function once but not disable my other  functions with `$('.jp-type-playlist .jp-playlist-item').click()`